# Como ler dados de um arquivo.txt

Tags: c

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma fila de bancos em C. Como posso ler entradas em um arquivo e assim atribuir valores a alguma variável específica do meu programa?

Exemplo: tenho uma variável **int qtd_caixas** na main. Preciso atribuir a essa variável um valor lido em um arquivo texto que será informado pelo usuário. 
(A formatação do arquivo não muda.)

*Exemplo de entrada:*

```
qtde de caixas = 9
delta t = 3
disciplina de escalonamento = {8,6,4,3,2}
//Aqui eu preciso armazenar um char "tipo da conta", um int "numero da 
conta" e outro int "numero de operações"
Comum - conta 997002 - 6 operacao(oes)
Prata - conta 520699 - 11 operacao(oes)
Prata - conta 932923 - 2 operacao(oes)
```

Código Atual:

```
int qtd_caixas, delta_t;
int e1, e2, e3, e4, e5;
char tipo_cliente[10];
int num_conta;
int operacoes;

FILE *arq = fopen("entrada-X.txt", "r+");
if(arq == NULL){
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Já tem diversas respostas falando sobre o assunto aqui no SOpt. Você precisa fazer um scan formatado em arquivo (`fscanf` a função que faz). Por exemplo, para ler da entrada padrão o formato que desejas, seria algo como `scanf("%s - conta %d - %d operacao(oes)", tipo_ciente, &num_conta, &operacoes)`; para ler do arquivo apontado por `arq`, seria `fscanf(arq, "%s - conta %d - %d operacao(oes)", tipo_ciente, &num_conta, &operacoes)`

Comment: Obrigado amigo, eu já tinha conseguido e esquecido de excluir a pergunta. No entanto, aproveitando seu comentário, outra dúvida: são 9999 possíveis casos de entrada, logo, é possível receber um argumento na linha de comando (ex: 0289) e ao abrir o arquivo fopen("entrada-X"), substituir o 'X' por esse argumento?  Algo como fopen("entrada-%d", X).

Comment: Essa resposta do Isac exibe o como fazer isso que desejas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344246/64969