# Como colocar um inteiro no final de uma string?

Tags: c, string

Eu preciso fazer um loop até `n` colocando um número inteiro no fim de uma string.

Ex: string `"E0"` e um inteiro de 0 a `n`, ficando algo assim:

> E00, E02, E03, ... , E0n

```
char ent[3] = {'E','0'};
char a[1];
int n=5;//exemplo

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        itoa(i,a,10);
       strcat(ent,a);
            printf("novo ent: %s \n ",ent);
        }
```

Não entendi o que está errado, pois está printando só a variavel `"a"` e não `"ent+a"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas para dar mais possibilidades às soluções apresentadas pelo @Isac.

### Uso alternativo de `sprintf`

```
int main() {
    char prefixo[3] = {'E','0'};
    char ent[4];//se quiser números com 2 casas decimais, basta por tamanho 5
    int n=5;//exemplo

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sprintf(ent, "%s%d", prefixo, i); //sprintf em vez de itoa
        printf("novo ent: %s \n ",ent);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Escrita de caracter direta

Você pode simplesmente computar o caracter desejado e pô-lo na posição 2 da string :

```
int main() {
    char ent[3] = {'E','0', '\0', '\0'};
    char num;
    int n=5;//exemplo

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        num = '0' + i; // calculando o caracter a partir de um offset i do caracter '0'
        ent[2] = num;
        printf("novo ent: %s \n ",ent);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> essa solução foi desenhada a números de um dígito, dá para fazer de jeito melhor

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro problema que faz com que o código não funcione é não estar a alocar espaço para o terminador na string que passa ao `itoa`. Lembre-se que o resultado é uma string corretamente terminada logo vai ter pelo menos dois carateres, o que você colocou e o terminador.

Por isso `char a[1]` tem que ser no minimo `char a[2]`. O próprio `itoa` é algo que nem deve utilizar pois não é *standard* e por isso não está disponivel em todos os compiladores, como no meu. Deve em vez disso usar [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) que é fácil na mesma e é *standard*.

O outro problema é que cada concatenação é permanente sobre a string `ent`. Por isso os seus textos vão crescendo: `E00`, `E001`, `E0012`, etc. A cada iteração do `for` tem que começar na string original, o que pode fazer se duplicar a original com [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) antes de usar.

Corrigindo esses dois problemas e mantendo o `itoa` ficaria assim:

```
int main() {
    char ent[3] = {'E','0'};
    char a[2];
    int n=5;//exemplo

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        itoa(i,a,10);
        char *ent_dup = strdup(ent); //criar duplicado
        strcat(ent_dup,a); //usar duplicado até ao fim
        printf("novo ent: %s \n ",ent_dup);
        free(ent_dup); //liberar duplicado
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note que tem que liberar a string devolvida por `strdup` através de `free` se quer evitar vazamentos de memória.

Utilizando `sprintf` ficaria assim:

```
int main() {
    char ent[3] = {'E','0'};
    char saida[10];
    int n=5;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sprintf(saida, "%s%01d", ent, i);
        printf("novo ent: %s \n ",saida);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja esta ultima versão no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Kj762j)

Comment: Acho que com seu uso do `sprintf`  seja desnecessário fazer concatenação com `strcat`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim é de facto. Apenas troquei o `sprintf` pelo `itoa` e nem me lembrei que dava para fazer tudo só com o `sprintf`. Obrigado pela comentário.

Comment: por nada. Coloquei uma resposta complementar que fazia mais sentido antes da sua edição. Acho que agora seria melhor mergear minha resposta na sua, que você acha?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Acho que não. Fica bom assim como está como complemento, e com uma variante de usar o ascii direto para quando numero tem só um  digito.